# Proof of purpose of travel to Georgia

Tags: visas, vacations, tbilisi

I am an Indian citizen planning to visit Georgia for vacation. This is my first trip abroad, but I have a valid US b1 visa on my passport, so I won't need a separate visa for Georgia. My questions are below:

1. Although I have a valid US visa, I have not traveled on it yet. Am I still exempt from applying for a Georgian visa if my US visa is fresh/not traveled.
2. What should I show as proof of purpose of travel? I am travelling solo, I don't know anyone there and don't have an invitation letter

Answer (score 2):

1. Yes, you are still exempt. Your US visa simply has to be valid, as stated both by the [Georgian MFA](https://www.geoconsul.gov.ge/HtmlPage/Html/View?id=26&lang=Eng), implicitly by [Georgia's E-Visa portal](https://www.evisa.gov.ge), and by [Timatic](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?SpecData=1&VISA=&page=visa&NA=IN&AR=00&PASSTYPES=PASS&DE=ge&user=KLMB2C&subuser=KLMB2C), the database used by airlines.
2. You will not normally be asked anything if your passport and US visa are in order, but to be safe, have a hotel booking confirmation, return flight confirmation, proof of travel insurance and either cash or a bank statement.